# zero times infinity in an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions defined on a ball $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq1$), satisfying
$$0\leq\int_{B}f(x)g(x)dx=f(x_{0})\int_{B}g(x)dx,$$ 
for some $x_{0}\in B$. My question is: if $f(x_{0})=0$, can we say that $\int_{B}g(x)dx$ is not $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot say that. Take $f\equiv 0$ and a $g$ whose integral is $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

This still works if $\int_Bg = \infty$.

The Lebesgue integral is defined for extended real-valued functions and the definition $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ is imposed. This is necessary to insure consistency.

The integral of a nonnegative function over a measurable E is defined as

$$\int_E f = \sup \left\{ \int_E g \,\,| \,\,g\,\, \text{measurable, of compact support, and } \, 0 \leqslant g \leqslant f\right\} $$
and if $f = 0$ we have $\int_E f = 0$ even if $m(E) = \infty$

Hence,

$$0 = \int_E 0 = 0 \cdot m(E) = 0 \cdot \infty$$

Thus, if $f(x_0) = 0$ and $\int_Bg = \infty$ then

$$f(x_0) \int_Bg = 0$$